# Multi-DB Transactions

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, transactions

Django Version 1.10.5 with Postgres 9.6.1

For the last year I've been working in a multi-schema default database environment. However things are beginning to grow to the point I've decided to split the single database into 3 databases.

I've got things working with a master/slave router for all 3 databases.

I am not using the 'default' database key. Instead I have 'db1', 'db2', and 'db3'

The part I am confused about is with transactions in this multi-database environment.

In this example it fails as expected. Caused of course by not using `@transaction.atomic(using='db1')` which is clear to me.

```
@transaction.atomic()
def edit(self, context):
    """Edit

    :param dict context: Context

    :return: None
    """

    # Check if employee exists
    try:
        result = Passport.objects.get(pk=self.user.employee_id)
    except Passport.DoesNotExist:
        return False

    result.name = context.get('name')

    result.save()
```

However I have this strange example, simply because I'm trying to understand... I would have expected this to fail but it does not:

```
@transaction.atomic(using='db1')
def edit(self, context):
    """Edit

    :param dict context: Context

    :return: None
    """

    # Check if employee exists
    try:
        result = Passport.objects.get(pk=self.user.employee_id)
    except Passport.DoesNotExist:
        return False

    result.name = context.get('name')

    with transaction.atomic(using='db2'):
        result.save()
```

The model `Passport` does not exist in DB2 models at all.

My router is setup so that all writes go to each respected DB.

So what is the purpose of setting the `using='db1'` in the atomic transaction? I've looked at the source and I see it defaults to `default` when not "using".

In the above example I even made another transaction inside of the initial transaction but this time `using='db2'` where the model doesn't even exist. I figured that would have failed, but it didn't and the data was written to the proper database.

I bring this up because there will be situations where I need to interact with all 3 databases and if a single problem occurs when writing to all 3 databases, all 3 need to be rolled back or if on success of everything, then committed of course.

Perhaps someone can help break this down for me so I can understand?

Comment: The whole excercise seems to be based on the wrong premise that postgresql cannot handle large amounts of data. It can. And it can do so far better than any other open source database

Comment: In fact I split these because of replication in a master/slave environment. 2 of the 3 databases do not need to be replicated at all. So to help remove the future strain, I made the split from multi-schema to multi-db

Comment: sounds reasonable but I am wondering if this is still worth the effort. Unless your master slave are far part, the cost (money and computing) of replicating the unwanted stuff will be negligible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're interpreting `transaction.atomic(using='X')` to mean: *run the following database commands on X, inside a transaction*.

In fact, it just means: *open a transaction on database X, and then either commit it or roll it back at the end of the block*.

Or, as the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) puts it:

> Under the hood, Django’s transaction management code:
>
> - opens a transaction when entering the outermost atomic block;
> - commits or rolls back the transaction when exiting the outermost block.

The question of which database to use for a given command is determined by your [router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers), not the `using` clause. So your `transaction.atomic(using='db2')` block is pointless (it will simply open a transaction on `db2` and then close it), but not an error.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. More or less I was simply over-thinking the situation. Even after reading so many documents, it was never 100% clear however, this has helped and it's what I was looking for.

Comment: I also ran into this and it really seemed like the documentation implied that the using parameter would have the same usage as it does elsewhere in Django, thanks for this answer.